# How to send an Image which is in uri file by email in c#

Tags: c#, image, email, uri

I want to send a picture via email through the code in c#, but I get the picture I need to send as a URI.
I saw that to send I need the location of the image but I only have the image as URI.

Is it possible?

Comment: Are you sending html enabled email?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a html enabled email in your mail body and refer the URI of image in the `<img>` tag.

e.g.

```
string message = @"<p>Photo:<br/> <img src='http://<URI to your image>' alt='Smiley face' height='42' width='42"></p>"

MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(from, to, subject, message);
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("localhost");
client.Send(mail);
```

or if you don't want to use URI in email then download and then embed your image in email body.

Comment: yes, i send with HTML. i tried this code but its didnt work, i accept in the email just symbols of image and no my image.

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of error & uri of image

Comment: No errors, the email has been sent but the image does not arrive

Comment: are you checking email in outlook or in browser? Outlook by default doesn't always download images you need to enable it. https://www.wintips.org/how-to-enable-pictures-download-in-outlook-email-messages/